# ionic 4 - how to retrieve data passed to a modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

According to the Ionic 4 docs, you can pass data via the componentProps property.
In Ionic3 I can retrieve it with the navParams Service. How do I do it in Ionic 4?

```
async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use @Input() decorator.

```
async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ModalPage',
  templateUrl: './ModalPage.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './ModalPage.component.css' ]
})
export class ModalPage  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @Input() value: any;
}
```

Comment: Note that the input value will not yet be available in the Component's constructor; to access it as early as possible, you will need to define the `ngAfterViewInit()` method.

Comment: how would you return data on modal dismiss ?

Comment: You need to use Subject and emit the data using next(). You can receive those values in Component using subscribe().

Answer (score 4):

Navparams still works in Ionic 4 Beta-15

**Page1.ts**

```
   import { ModalPage } from './modal.page';

   async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });

    //insert onDidDismiss() here

    return await modal.present();
   }
```

**ModalPage.ts**

```
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

  export class ModalPage {
  public value = this.navParams.get('value');

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {}

}
```

To get a returned value from the ModaPage to Page1:

**Page1.ts**

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

**IMPORTANT:**

1. To use `ModalPage` inside `Page1` you need to import `ModalPageModule` module inside `page1.module.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your modal page module name into the `app-module.ts` under `import:[ your -modal-module-page-name]`.  If you want to call a modal into a page there is no need to call into the page-module

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { CountryCodePage } from '../country-code/country-code.page';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
    })
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

      constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      openCountryModal(){
    this.presentModal();
      }


      async presentModal() {
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
          component: CountryCodePage,
          componentProps:{"dataArr":{
            FirstName:"chitranjan",
            Lastname:"soni",
            Ambition :"coding"
          }}
        });
        return await modal.present();
      }
    }

    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


    import { Component, OnInit ,Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-country-code',
      templateUrl: './country-code.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./country-code.page.scss'],
    })
    export class CountryCodePage implements OnInit {
      @Input() dataArr: string;
      constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(navParams.get('dataArr')));
       }
      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }


<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CountryCodePageModule } from './country-code/country-code.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,CountryCodePageModule,
    HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**homepage**

async presentModal(urlm) {

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: ShowmediaPage,
  componentProps: { url: urlm ,
  from:status},
});

return await modal.present();
```

}

**ShowmediaPage**

@Input() url: string;

@Input() from:string;

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.